# Read from pytables hdf5 file in joblib parallel loop

Tags: parallel-processing, hdf5, pytables, joblib

I'm struggling to access data in a joblib parallel for loop.

The basic idea is I want to load data from a h5 file in every iteration, do something with the data, and save the output. The amount of data is just to large that it doesn't fit in the memory. For this reason I was thinking of a iterative method.

My basic example is something like this:

```
import tables
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed 

# open file
h5file = tables.open_file('file.h5','r')

# define function which I want to run in parallel
def function(i):
    x = h5file.root.variable[:,i]
    
    # do something with x, e.g.
    result = np.sum(np.square(x))

    return(result)

# run in parallel
results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(function)(i) for i in range(100))

# close file
h5file.close()
```

But if I'm implementing this in this way I get the following error:
"PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers."

I am really clueless and would be very happy about help.

Answer (score 0):

I got my mistake: I need to open and close the file in the function I want to parallelize:

```
import tables
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed 


# define function which I want to run in parallel
def function(i):
    # open file
    h5file = tables.open_file('file.h5','r')
    
    x = h5file.root.variable[:,i]
    
    # close file
    h5file.close()
    
    # do something with x, e.g.
    result = np.sum(np.square(x))

    return(result)



# run in parallel
results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(function)(i) for i in range(100))
```